# MariaDB very simple MATCH-AGAINST query not using FULLTEXT index?

Tags: sql, mariadb, full-text-search, explain

I have the following table as displayed by `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `lname` (
  `lnameid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `lid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `namerank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lnameid`),
  KEY `lid` (`lid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `lname_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lid`) REFERENCES `sl` (`slid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

This table has about 230,000 rows. All rows have non-NULL values for the name column.

I have the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT MATCH(lname.name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS nms FROM lname;
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | lname           | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 228370 |       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

My question is: I see `possible_keys` is `NULL` (and `Extra` is empty), does it mean that my `FULLTEXT` index is somehow not being used?

The query seems slow to execute.

I'm using MariaDB 10.5.19 on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is calculating a match coefficient  for **all** rows, so no index is needed, but when you change it to

```
CREATE TABLE `lname` (
  `lnameid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `lid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `namerank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lnameid`),
  KEY `lid` (`lid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)#,
  #CONSTRAINT `lname_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lid`) REFERENCES `sl` (`slid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

```
INSERT INTO  lname vALUES (1,1,'a',1,1)
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT MATCH(name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS nms FROM lname
  WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 1;
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | lname | fulltext | name | name | 0 |  | 1 | Using where |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mY6qaaJO)

In this case the database must look for fitting matches, and so needs to use the index to find corresponding rows faster